# Parametric v Non-Parametric?

Tags: p-value, normality-assumption, large-data, nonparametric

I've recently began doing some data analysis for a sample of around 5800 respondents who are categorised into four different groups in relation to different levels of psychological connection in a community-based sport.

When testing for normality, all of my tests are returning as significant (p-values; Kolmogorov and Shapiro-Wilk) and have shown a moderate to strong deviation from the normal range of skewness and kurtosis. I've also identified a number of outliers which are not faulty - e.g., are not incorrectly measured or affected by human response error.

My first understanding was that as normality was not assumed, then non-parametric tests should be conducted to further examine the results - and in my case it seems as though it would most likely be a Kruskal-Wallis test. However, as a result of the large sample size, I have received advice to use parametric tests as although the assumptions of normality have not been assumed, the sample size should counteract that issue and should not undermine the validity of parametric tests? I've also received advice to simply do the initial normality tests and present the results without conducting any additional parametric or non-parametric testing (*for example; normality tests were conducted, the p-value was significant (p-value score) with the skewness and kurtosis indicating moderate deviations from normality, however, as a result of the large sample size, no further testing is required (as supported by....)*), again, due to the size of the sample with citations to support this approach provided when advice has been provided.

If anyone has any constructive feedback / advice, that would be great :)

Comment: Possibly of interest: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/464327/247274

Comment: I'm not sure where this idea that normality is the only parametric model originated but it's a disastrous falsehood (many posts and comments on site address this). If you have a textbook that tells you something like this, I'd love to know its title; I'm collecting examples in the hope of working on a comprehensve correction of the alarmingly widespread misconception.

Comment: Hi Glen, thanks firstly for your comment. I'm however struggling to understand what you mean by the following; I'm not sure where this idea that normality is the only parametric model originated but it's a disastrous falsehood (many posts and comments on site address this). Are you concluding that violations of normality is not an issue?

Comment: Not at all. It's the progress from "I'm not prepared to assume normality" to "Therefore I cannot make any specific distributional assumption at all". This *normality-or-nothing* premise is a false dichotomy.  [There's a second issue about whether it's reasonable to hold the premise that you should test your assumptions, but that's a whole other thing; let's get this one clear first]

Comment: That's not to say a nonparametric test is a bad choice but ruling out every other parametric possibility without at least some consideration seems premature. It's the source of that (nonnormal$\implies$nonparametric) idea I was asking about. Can  you also say something about the way your DV is measured/what sort of values it takes? Can you say more about the specific null and alternative hypotheses you had (or at least your working hypothesis/question of interest)?

Comment: Returning to the suitability of testing your assumptions note that with a large number of observtations, you're very likely to reject even reasonably small - perhaps even inconsequential deviations from assumptions. Formal testing will lead you to avoid reasonable assumptions while being unconcerned with much risker ones (on smaller samples).

Comment: Hi Glen, I am still not sure if I am comprehending correctly what you have communicated with me, so let me see if what I’ve interpreted aligns with your comments. I will address each of your comments one by one with a number in brackets as an indication of my own reply.

Comment: (1) Are you saying that (from the point above) although other researchers have concluded/expressed that you can simply present your results after running initial normality tests where normality is violated, and move on, this process is not correct, or appropriately handled?

Comment: (2) Again, are you saying that because the data is non-normal, this doesn’t necessarily mean that non-parametric tests should be used, and furthermore, more consideration should be given to select the most appropriate testing after normality is violated? When you mention consideration of other parametric possibilities, what are some examples you would be referring to?

Comment: (3) So, the large sample size creates a level of sensitivity which can in turn negatively affect the results such as rejecting even only small deviations?